# Laravel does not load my views

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm developing a web application with laravel 4.2 (PHP 5.4.25) as backend framework.

When I run my index page from IDE, it returns me the first view that I expected, but when I call it from the browser it shows me this error:

```
substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

This is a screen of the error

[image]

This is my route files:

```
<?php

// Route to home page
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () {
    Log::debug('**** Load home page view');
    if ( Auth::check() ) {
        return View::make('dashboard');
    } else {
        return View::make('login');
    }
}));
```

I've extract the contents of public folder of laravel inside the root, and after I've updated the path of the start files. However the index file if is run inside the IDE (PHPStorm) works fine and return me the login view.

Login view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm wrong?

---

**EDIT:** The problem is in the `app/config/session.php` file, I changed that file with the orginal laravel file and all works fine.

Here my wrong config session file:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'database',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => DB::connection('mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

);
```

---

Thanks

Comment: In your view are you using `Str::endsWith($something)` or function `ends_with($something)` ?

Comment: @DavidBarker No, my view is empty.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong. When you run from IDE does it display this empty Login page? What url do you launch in your browser? Do you have only `login.php` file or maybe also `login.blade.php` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek When I run index.php from my IDE, it returns me the HTML in the console. The url that I call from the browser is: http://localhost:8888/my-project. I've only `login.php`.

Comment: Could you show us also `dasboard.php` file ?

Comment: I'm afraid error is in another piece of code. What if you put in this route instead of any template just `return 'test';`? I assume you will also have this error so probably you change also something else in your code.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yes, you're right, Also if I change my route in this way `Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () { echo "test"; }));` I've the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `app/config/session.php`.

I've replaced `'connection' => DB::connection('mysql'),` with `'connection' => null,` and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the error dumped, this is not a problem in your view but, somehow, in your database connection. Database manager is not able to parse your database connection name. That may be caused by `Auth::check()`. Check if your database is properly configured.

Comment: I've developed and run a lot of unit test that used the DB. Now I've tried to change my route in this way: `Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () { return View::make('login'); }));` but when I call the index page it returns me the same error.

Comment: I'm not seeing all of your code, but what I can tell is that something is trying to hit your database, maybe another package?

Comment: I've checked it and it's not DB problem. Even if you put into your database invalid connection data what's quite strange `Auth::check()` won't throw any Exception .

Comment: Check the full stack list, usually down the list you can tell which class is doing it.